# Move storage spaces from Windows 10 Pro to Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, pool

I have a storage space with multiple physical disks in Windows 10 Pro, but now I want to switch to windows server 2016. I will probably do a clean installation of Windows Server.

Will Windows Server 2016 recognize the pool of disks and volumes or will I have to reformat. Although I have a backup, I am really trying to avoid any data loss here.

Any thoughts on how I can move to WS2016 and still keep the data in the pool?

Comment: you're talking about Storage Spaces, right? If that's the case, you should be fine: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/what-happens-to-my-storage-spaces-pool-if-i-need/5f30b59a-e9f1-4610-974a-1c51230730c5?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

I just did a Win 10 Pro to Server 2016 Standard switch. All of my OSes are fully updated.
The windows server 2016 standard failed to recognize all of my mirrored pool created by Windows 10, while Get-PhysicalDisk command in PowerShell only tells me all of my pooled drives' "OperationalStatus" are "Starting".
After doing some research, I guess you'll need to recreate pools in WS2016.